# Rename Column name in Pivot query and format its time value in format HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am preparing one report for which I need to have sum of time taken by various processes in column 2.

I am sharing small snippet in which I am not able to figure out. Below is the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM CTE_NAME
PIVOT ( SUM(TIME) FOR ACTIVITY IN ( NULL
,Process 1
,Process 2
    )
) order by 2 desc
```

[image: Output of my query]

**Things to be noted**:-

1. hours_diff is the value calculated in a CTE expression above this shared snippet
2. hours_diff is of `date` type.

**Things to be done**:-

1. It is required to change the Column name `NULL` to `TOTAL_TIME`
2. It is required to convert the value of `TIME` to `HH:MM:SS`

**Things I have tried**:-

1. I tried using `SUM(TIME) AS TOTAL_TIME ...` it didn't seem to work. Also after that I tried replacing `NULL` with `TOTAL_TIME` but it changed in a way that `TIME` values of `Process 1` shifted towards column 2.
2. In order to convert the time value (which is in seconds). I have this previously used `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sec_diff/3600),'FM9900') || ':' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(sec_diff,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR(MOD(sec_diff,60),'FM00') as time_diff`. But as I am unable to fetch the column from above snippet I am not able to convert the values to `HH:MM:SS`
3. If I convert the value of `TIME` inside CTE then `SUM` function in `SELECT` query throws error `Invalid Number` as the value being passed to SUM function is in format `HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 1):

For giving name to the column, you can provide name in `IN` list of `PIVOT` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM CTE_NAME
PIVOT ( SUM(TIME) FOR ACTIVITY
 IN ( NULL as TOTAL_TIME, -- THIS
,Process 1
,Process 2
    )
) order by 2 desc;
```

To calculate `HH:MI:SS` from seconds, use this in select.(works for seconds in diff is less than 86400(1 day)

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * YOUR_COLUMN_SECONDS, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or following will work for any bigger values

```
Lpad(Trunc(your_column_seconds/86400),2,'0') 
|| ':' || 
Lpad(Trunc(your_column_seconds/1440),2,'0') 
|| ':' || 
Lpad(Trunc(your_column_seconds/60),2,'0')
```

**Note**: column name of seconds difference generated by pivot should be used in above expression.

Comment: I will be using the same ```TOTAL_TIME``` for conversion. Do I need to add  ```Lpad``` shared by you as part of same select query or how I can proceed for the same?

Comment: Also rename part worked fine. Thanks for suggesting that change.. Only part left is conversion now..

Comment: Yes, LPAD is used to pad 0 if any value in the HH:MI:SS is single digit.